# Microsoft Insight Java Set Operation Name Singleton

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-application-insights

I have REST endpoint with code:

```
telemetry.getContext().getOperation().setName(insightEvent.getOperationName());
telemetry.trackEvent(insightEvent.name, insightEvent.getProperties(), null);
```

Telemetry is TelemetryClient (field of that controller).

I post insights from WWW to API, but there is problem with this line. My app works multi-threaded, so sometimes INSIGHT_A change operation name and before trackEvent is called INSIGHT_B change operationName again. Should I implement critical section on these 2 lines? Or how should i repair it?

I was thinking that critical section is ok to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

- Using synchronization mechanisms like `synchronized` can introduce contention and may impact the performance of the application, especially in a highly concurrent environment.

I have modified the code to use a synchronized block or a similar mechanism.

Using a **synchronized block:**

```java
public class YourController {

    private final TelemetryClient telemetry;

    // Other constructor and initialization code

    public void yourEndpointMethod(InsightEvent insightEvent) {
        synchronized (telemetry) {
            telemetry.getContext().getOperation().setName(insightEvent.getOperationName());
            telemetry.trackEvent(insightEvent.name, insightEvent.getProperties(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Iam using a build tool like Maven, add dependencies for the telemetry library.

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>applicationinsights-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.18</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

- The `telemetry` object is used as the lock for synchronization. The synchronized block ensures that only one thread can execute the code inside it at a time.

[image]

If performance is a critical concern, you might want to consider other concurrency control mechanisms, such as `ReentrantLock` or using atomic operations.